# Wired Home network on Mac with very limited speed transfer

Tags: macos, networking, wireless-networking, router

This is the network setup I have:

1. I have a 100 Mbps fiber optic Internet line
2. I have a wifi router. 1 ethernet port is connected to a Rasperry Pi and another one is to Netgear WNDR3700 (which gives speeds of up to 300 Mbps) connected with a wired ethernet cable 30 meters away.
3. I have set it up as a bridge, so in that way, when I connect my Mac to the Netgear I have access also to the Rasperry Pi

Now, when I try to copy a file the speed transfers are VERY slow...

1. I have a hard-drive attached to the Raspberry, and I have shared it with Samba
2. I have also tried doing an scp from my Mac to the Rasperry:

`scp test.avi root@192.168.1.42:/media/maxtor/Movies test.avi 89% 4005MB 918.7KB/s 08:45 ETA`

The speeds rates I get are VERY slow (below 1 Mb/s).. In fact, I get faster speeds in downloading a file over the Internet on Wifi, than having a wired file transfer between my Mac and my Rasperry.

Any ideas what I may be doing wrong?

(P.D. my networking knowledge/systems is very limited, so i may have used wrong terminology).

Comment: Measure your networking speed with a good efficient network performance testing tool like IPerf (not high-overhead protocols like SMB or scp and not with disks involved) and mind your units. Networking speeds are usually given in 10^3, 10^6, 10^9 1-bit bits per second. Disk and file I/O are usually given in 2^10, 2^20, 2^30 8-bit Bytes per second. If you're doing disk or file I/O *over the network*, it's hard to know which units your tool is reporting to you.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the problem is not the network. The raspberry pi is likly not able to handle more transfer cpu-wise ( having only 100Mbit network limits the raspberry to max 10MB/sek)

Please check the load of the raspberry during a copy process. open a interactive ssh session and watch "top" . If the CPU jumps to 100% and stays there, thats likely the problem.

Also the raspberry pi uses the USB2.0 bus for it's network interface, so you are sharing the usb2.0 bus  between the external USB disk and the network.

Try a copy to the internal storage of the pi, if that's substantially faster, there you go.

More detailed explanation here : http://www.howtoeverything.net/linux/raspberry-pi/performance-issues-when-copying-files-over-network

Comment: Thanks for your reply! That was actually my initial thought. The RPi's CPU doesn't really spike. In fact, I have tried copying between 2 Macs, i.e. one of the shares a Hard Drive a via Samba, and the other Mac writes files to it. both connected on Ethernet. I get the same speed transfers of less than 1 Mb/s. This makes me suspect that there is something wrong with my network or Mac setup.

Answer (score 0):

What is your hard drive file system ?

I had the exact same problem, i solved it by :

1. Using EXT4 instead of NTFS
2. Using Netatalk (AFP) instead of Samba

Now i can upload files from Mac to Pi at 4Mo/s

If that doesn't solve your problem, you might want to check this great answer on raspberry pi forum :

http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=374296#p374296